# Como enviar un objeto/array desde node a pug (jade) y renderizarlo?

Tags: nodejs, array, jade, pug

Desde node tengo algo así:

```
var nombres = ['Saab','Volvo','BMW'];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {nombres: nombres});
});
```

luego en pug:

```
- var nombres1 = {nombres};
html(lang="es")
head
title= "Itris INFO"
body
script.
  console.log(!{JSON.stringify(nombres1)});
ul
  each nombre in nombres1
    li= nombre
```

Pero cuando renderiza, en el html me muestra:

- Saab,Volvo,BMW

Y la idea es que muestre algo así:

- Saab
- Volvo
- BMW

Probé todas las opciones que dicen en otros post sobre esto y nada funciona.
El tag script lo agregue a efectos de ver el objeto en la consola, y ahí si me muestra un array de 3 elementos. Sin embargo, cuando lo utilizo en pug no funciona... no se si toma como un string o que...

Comment: te aseguro que son los espacios, solamente eso los espacios

Comment: Ah si... error mio... pero ahora tiene otro problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intenta esto**

//Routes

```
 app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   let nombres = ['Saab','Volvo','BMW'];
   res.render('index',{nombres}); // o {'nombres':nombres}
 });
```

//views/index.pug

```
ul
  each nombre in nombres
       li= nombre
```

Fuente: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: No... todo lo que esta en la documentación ya lo probé... creo que hay algo con el JSON.stringify pero no puedo terminar de determinarlo...

Comment: Puedes mostrarme mas detalles? de la variable que estas mandando, para poderte ayudar

Comment: SI, ahi agregue mas detalles... es tan simple como mandar un array y querer replicarlo en el template como una lista de esos 3 elementos... pero nada funciona... La variable que mando es justamente el array que esta en la primer linea del javascript

Comment: Amigo ami me funciona
`app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  let nombres = ['Saab','Volvo','BMW'];
  res.render('index',{nombres});
});`

Comment: Pero y como haces en pug para que se vea los li uno debajo del otro? Ahi es donde no me funciona...

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, tal vez lo estás enviando mal, veo que todavía lo recibes en una variable en pug , se puede pero ya lo mandas en una variable al template , no veo por que volverlo a poner , aparte tienes mal la parte de res.render('someView',{"nombres":nombres}) , el tipo string es la key con la cual lo vas a identificar en el template el otro valor después de los **:** es lo que va contener, puede ser un número , un string , un Array , un objeto , etc , corrige eso y me dices

Comment: Bueno probé todo lo que me dijiste... y lo mismo... por casualidad vos lo estas probando y te da bien??

Comment: Si hice una prueba rápida. te lo muestro, espera lo subo a github, y te mando el link

Comment: uh joya a ver si lo resuelvo, hace exactamente 8 horas que estoy con esto :(. Asi se aprende dicen...

Comment: Si amigo, exactamente a veces asi sucede , tienes que estar buscando y a veces es un error minimo, poco a poco, es cuestion de dedicarle tiempo a esto. Toma: https://github.com/NachoCodeX/DamianMaenza

Comment: Mira, si ejecuto tal cual lo que vos me pasaste, me dispara un error (no reconoce nombres como array ni como nada.... solo me funciona si lo pongo con llaves {nombres}, pero me pone los items uno al lado del otro. Este error me tira... (estoy compilando con gulp), lo pongo en  otra respuesta...

Comment: Amigo que es lo que compilas? El pug ? Para que te dé un html  , Puedes utilizarlo así , si le indicas que "View engine" que vas a ocupar , no necesitas procesarlo con Glup , puedes utilizarlo así. Tal vez ese sea tu problema.

Comment: Olvidate, corri el que me pasaste clonado directamente y anda perfecto... me queda mañana revisar mi codigo y ver porque el mio explota. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH jajajajjajaa.... ese debe ser mi problema entonces!!! No se como pero mañana lo voy a investigar mejor jajaa. GRACIASSS

Comment: Jajaja vale amigo , de nada cualquier cosa me avisas. Tienes mi cuenta de Github , tengo algunos proyectos , y estaré subiendo más de Nodejs + Express , pronto subire uno de autentificación con Passport.js

Comment: Lo probe y era eso... no se porque si tiene el html en la carpeta de las views hace esa cosa rara... borre el html y funciono de maravilla... muchas gracias por la paciencia y tu tiempo. Me voy a dormir tranquilo :)

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado , cualquier duda sobres Javascript o Python. Intenta ver videos los videos de Carlos Azaustre  en Youtube  sobres Nodejs +Express.js + mongoose, explica muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
each nombre, i in nombres
  li #{nombre}
```

[Adjunto un enlace sobre la sintaxis de Jade.](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/)

Comment: Si lo habia probado.... pero devuelve lo mismo: * Saab,Volvo,BMW